# JQuery image slider one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slider, intervals

I have those pictures

```
<img class=img src='a' />
<img class=img src='b' />
<img class=img src='c' />
<img class=img src='d' />
<img class=img src='e' />
```

And this button

```
 <button id=presstostart>PRESS ME TO START</button>
```

I want once the button is clicked start showing the pictures one by one, `a,b,c,d,e` with an interval of 2 seconds amongst them.In JQuery.No plugins....

Answer (score 0):

I found an example in this url

http://www.jssor.com/development/index.html

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
    <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
        <div><img u="image" src="image1.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="image2.jpg" /></div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- it works the same with all jquery version from 1.x to 2.x -->
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jssor.slider.mini.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var options = { $AutoPlay: true };
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);
    });
</script>
```

You will have to download the js library from the link above, and instead of on ready you could assign the event to a click of a button.

yet another example...
http://jsfiddle.net/7WL6P/200/

Answer (score 0):

There are many slider plugins you can use. But personally I would recommend [flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) and [nivoslider](http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/nivo-slider). They're easy to use and customize. You can also find attributes to set animation speed, pause time, slide direction, etc.